# Sending subsequent messages in rosjava leads to message loss [solved]

Tags: ros, messages, rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

I encountered some problems with the ROSJava listener. I have a very simple node in ROS that sends two subsequent messages through the same publisher/topic. When i'm looking at the topic through "rostopic echo" all messages are send in their order and none is lost. But the ROSJava Listener only gets the first message and occasionally the second. Some of the messages appear to be lost.
When i'm putting manually some time in between the two publish attempts the listener starts receiving all messages in order and none is lost.

Heres a log example. Thats what i'm getting on the topic:

```
data: 1: Message_1
---
data: 1: Message_2
---
data: 2: Message_1
---
data: 2: Message_2
---
data: 3: Message_1
---
data: 3: Message_2
---
data: 4: Message_1
---
data: 4: Message_2
---
data: 5: Message_1
---
data: 5: Message_2
---
data: 6: Message_1
---
data: 6: Message_2
---
data: 7: Message_1
---
data: 7: Message_2
---
data: 8: Message_1
---
data: 8: Message_2
---
data: 9: Message_1
---
data: 9: Message_2
---
data: 10: Message_1
---
data: 10: Message_2
---
data: 11: Message_1
---
data: 11: Message_2
---
data: 12: Message_1
---
data: 12: Message_2
---
data: 13: Message_1
---
data: 13: Message_2
---
data: 14: Message_1
---
data: 14: Message_2
---
data: 15: Message_1
---
data: 15: Message_2
---
data: 16: Message_1
---
data: 16: Message_2
---
data: 17: Message_1
---
data: 17: Message_2
---
data: 18: Message_1
---
data: 18: Message_2
---
data: 19: Message_1
---
data: 19: Message_2
---
data: 20: Message_1
---
data: 20: Message_2
---
data: 21: Message_1
---
data: 21: Message_2
---
data: 22: Message_1
---
data: 22: Message_2
---
data: 23: Message_1
---
data: 23: Message_2
---
data: 24: Message_1
---
data: 24: Message_2
---
data: 25: Message_1
---
data: 25: Message_2
---
data: 26: Message_1
---
data: 26: Message_2
---
data: 27: Message_1
---
data: 27: Message_2
---
data: 28: Message_1
---
data: 28: Message_2
---
data: 29: Message_1
---
data: 29: Message_2
```

And heres what the listener gets:

```
INFO: I heard: "1: Message_2"
Aug 23, 2013 1:04:57 PM org.ros.internal.node.RosoutLogger info
INFO: I heard: "2: Message_2"
Aug 23, 2013 1:04:57 PM org.ros.internal.node.RosoutLogger info
INFO: I heard: "2: Message_2"
Aug 23, 2013 1:04:57 PM org.ros.internal.node.RosoutLogger info
INFO: I heard: "3: Message_2"
Aug 23, 2013 1:04:57 PM org.ros.internal.node.RosoutLogger info
INFO: I heard: "4: Message_1"
Aug 23, 2013 1:04:57 PM org.ros.internal.node.RosoutLogger info
INFO: I heard: "4: Message_2"
Aug 23, 2013 1:04:57 PM org.ros.internal.node.RosoutLogger info
INFO: I heard: "5: Message_2"
Aug 23, 2013 1:04:57 PM org.ros.internal.node.RosoutLogger info
INFO: I heard: "6: Message_2"
Aug 23, 2013 1:04:57 PM org.ros.internal.node.RosoutLogger info
INFO: I heard: "7: Message_2"
Aug 23, 2013 1:04:57 PM org.ros.internal.node.RosoutLogger info
INFO: I heard: "8: Message_2"
Aug 23, 2013 1:04:57 PM org.ros.internal.node.RosoutLogger info
INFO: I heard: "9: Message_2"
Aug 23, 2013 1:04:57 PM org.ros.internal.node.RosoutLogger info
INFO: I heard: "10: Message_2"
Aug 23, 2013 1:04:57 PM org.ros.internal.node.RosoutLogger info
INFO: I heard: "11: Message_2"
Aug 23, 2013 1:04:57 PM org.ros.internal.node.RosoutLogger info
INFO: I heard: "12: Message_2"
Aug 23, 2013 1:04:58 PM org.ros.internal.node.RosoutLogger info
INFO: I heard: "13: Message_2"
Aug 23, 2013 1:04:58 PM org.ros.internal.node.RosoutLogger info
INFO: I heard: "14: Message_2"
Aug 23, 2013 1:04:58 PM org.ros.internal.node.RosoutLogger info
INFO: I heard: "15: Message_2"
Aug 23, 2013 1:04:58 PM org.ros.internal.node.RosoutLogger info
INFO: I heard: "16: Message_2"
Aug 23, 2013 1:04:58 PM org.ros.internal.node.RosoutLogger info
INFO: I heard: "17: Message_2"
Aug 23, 2013 1:04:58 PM org.ros.internal.node.RosoutLogger info
INFO: I heard: "18: Message_2"
Aug 23, 2013 1:04:58 PM org.ros.internal.node.RosoutLogger info
INFO: I heard: "19: Message_2"
Aug 23, 2013 1:04:58 PM org.ros.internal.node.RosoutLogger info
INFO: I heard: "20: Message_2"
Aug 23, 2013 1:04:58 PM org.ros.internal.node.RosoutLogger info
INFO: I heard: "21: Message_2"
Aug 23, 2013 1:04:58 PM org.ros.internal.node.RosoutLogger info
INFO: I heard: "22: Message_2"
Aug 23, 2013 1:04:58 PM org.ros.internal.node.RosoutLogger info
INFO: I heard: "23: Message_2"
Aug 23, 2013 1:04:58 PM org.ros.internal.node.RosoutLogger info
INFO: I heard: "24: Message_2"
Aug 23, 2013 1:04:58 PM org.ros.internal.node.RosoutLogger info
INFO: I heard: "25: Message_2"
Aug 23, 2013 1:04:58 PM org.ros.internal.node.RosoutLogger info
INFO: I heard: "26: Message_2"
Aug 23, 2013 1:04:58 PM org.ros.internal.node.RosoutLogger info
INFO: I heard: "27: Message_2"
Aug 23, 2013 1:04:58 PM org.ros.internal.node.RosoutLogger info
INFO: I heard: "28: Message_1"
```

There is a huge gap between

```
INFO: I heard: "4: Message_1"
Aug 23, 2013 1:04:57 PM org.ros.internal.node.RosoutLogger info
```

and

```
Aug 23, 2013 1:04:58 PM org.ros.internal.node.RosoutLogger info
INFO: I heard: "28: Message_1"
```

Strange to say that i don't loose any "Message_2"...

Anyone got an idea what could cause it? I'm basically using the ROSJava Listener Tutorial and nothing else. So there shouldn't be anything wrong with the code. I'm using the latest ROSJava revision.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/74509/sending-subsequent-messages-in-rosjava-leads-to-message-loss-%5Bsolved%5D/) by [Kircheis](https://answers.ros.org/users/4373/kircheis/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2013-08-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So i found a solution. If you use the standard "addMessageListener" method for a subscriber than the internal queue size will be set to 1 (see for example DefaultSubscriber.java). Luckily you can set it yourself with the second "addMessageListener" method which offers a limit parameter. A simple int for the queue size.

---

Originally posted by [Kircheis](https://answers.ros.org/users/4373/kircheis/) with karma: 18 on 2013-08-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0